# switching div class between divs (jquery, javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I think this should be a  pretty common jquery function but I just couldn't find anything about it.

say I have 10 divs and each div trigger an event when clicked. So when I cilck a div, jquery adds a class, say "clicked" to the div. But how can I set it so when I click another div, it removes the previous div class "clicked" and gives it to the div that I just clicked?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("div.groupname").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("clicked").siblings().removeClass("clicked");
});
```

or:

```
$("div.groupname").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("clicked").end().addClass("clicked");
});
```

[**You can try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/whc5B/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.one').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('two');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('two');
});
```

css

```
.one{
    background:red;
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.two{
    background:green;
}
```

html

```
<div class="one">
</div>

<div class="one">
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/fNWxf/

Comment: You can also chain the two lines: `$(this).addClass('two').siblings().removeClass('two');`